# Spivak's Calculus, Ch 13 "Integrals, Prob *27: $f$ integrable on $[a,b]$ there are cont. fns $g\leq f \leq h$ with $\int_a^b h - \int_a^b g<\epsilon$.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation

The following is a problem from Chapter 13 "Integrals" from Spivak's Calculus

> *27. Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there are continuous functions $g\leq f \leq h$ with
> $\int_a^b h-\int_a^b g<\epsilon$. Hint: First get step functions with
> this property, and then continuous ones. A picture will help
> immensely.

**The solution manual says**

> It obviously suffices to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there are
> $g\leq f$ with $\int_a^b f - \int_a^b g < \epsilon$ and $h \geq f$
> with $\int_a^b h - \int_a^b f<\epsilon$. Moreover, the second follows
> from the first by considering $-f$, so we just have to find the
> desired $g \leq f$.
>
> Chose a step function $s \leq f$ with $\int_a^bf - \int_a^b
>  s<\epsilon/2$, by Problem 26(a). Choose $M\geq 1$ so that $|f(x)|\leq
>  M$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, and if $s$ is constant on $(t_{i-1},t_i)$
> for $i=1,...,n$, choose $\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{2nM}$. Let $g=s$ on
> $[t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}, t_i-\frac{\delta}{2}]$ and let $g$ be a
> linear function on $[t_i-\frac{\delta}{2},t_i]$ and $[t_i,
>  t_i+\frac{\delta}{2}]$, with $g(t_i)=-M$.
>
> Then $g\leq s \leq f$ and $\int_a^b s - \int_a^b g \leq
>  nM\delta<\epsilon/2$ so $\int_a^b f - \int_a^b g <\epsilon$.

**My question is about the very last line in the above proof.** Let me go through the proof again, but with more intermediate steps to make sure the reasoning is all correct.

If $f$ is integrable, we can always find a step function $s \leq f$ such that $\int_a^b f - \int_a^b s < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ (this is a result proved in a previous problem, 26a).

I'm using $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ here instead of $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so that in the end we obtain $\int_a^b f - \int_a^b g < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which, when combined with $\int_a^b h - \int_a^b f < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ gives us our desired result: $\int_a^b h - \int_a^b g < \epsilon$.

Since $f$ is integrable (see edit below for definition of "integrable" being used), it is bounded, and there is some $M \geq 1$ such that

$$\forall x, x \in [a,b] \implies |f(x)|\leq M$$

Given a partition $P=\{t_0,...,t_n\}$, $s$ is constant on $(t_{i-1},t_i)$, for $i=1,...,n$.

Let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{4nM}$.

Now let's define a function $g$. For $i=1,...,n$, let

- $g=s$ on $[t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}, t_i-\frac{\delta}{2}]$
- $g$ linear on $[t_i-\frac{\delta}{2},t_i]$ and $[t_i, t_i+\frac{\delta}{2}]$, with $g(t_i)=-M$.

For the $i^{th}$ partition subinterval, $[t_{i-1},t_i]$, I believe $g$ looks something like the following

[image]

And this is what I believe $g$ looks like for an entire interval $[a,b]$

[image]

**So here is the part my question is about.**

Let $s_i$ denote the constant value of the step function $s$ in the $i^{th}$ partition subinterval. Then

$$\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} s = s_i (t_i-t_{i-1})=s_i \Delta t_i$$

$$\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} g = \left [ (t_i+\frac{\delta}{2})-(t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}) \right ] \cdot s_i + N_i$$

$$=s_i\Delta t_i -s_i\delta +N_i$$

where $N_i$ corresponds to the integral of $g$ on the increasing and decreasing portions in a subinterval, ie on the edges of a subinterval.

I believe $N_i<0$. I won't prove it here, but unless I am mistaken, it is pretty clear it must be so.

Now, if this $N_i$ term did not exist here, it seems we'd have exactly the same solution as the solution manual, namely

$$\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} s-\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} g = s_i\delta\leq M\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{4n}$$

Since we have $n$ subintervals then

$$\int_a^b s-\int_a^b g \leq n\frac{\epsilon}{4n}=\frac{\epsilon}{4}$$

But the term $N_i$ does exist in each subinterval. Is there a mistake in my reasoning?

On the other hand, it also seems clear that we could assert that

$$\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} s-\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} g < 2M\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2n}$$

so

$$\int_a^b s-\int_a^b g \leq n\frac{\epsilon}{2n}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

**How did the solution manual come up with $\int_a^b s - \int_a^b g \leq
 nM\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$?**

Edit: the definition of integral used is the one present in Spivak's Calculus.

> **Definition:** A function $f$ which is bounded on $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if $\sup\{L(f,P)\}=\inf\{U(f,P)\}$. This common
> number is called the integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Integrable functions aren’t necessarily bounded. What’s your definition of integrable?

Comment: @FShrike A function $f$ which is bounded on $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if $\sup\{L(f,P)\}=\inf\{U(f,P)\}$, and if this is the case then this common number is denoted $\int_a^b f$, and called the integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$. (Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 13)

Comment: You should add in your post that you presuppose the function should be bounded! More generally we don’t assert integrable -> bounded

Answer (score 2):

First we split the integral into three parts: the left edge where g is increasing, the middle portion where it is constant and coincides with the step function, and the right edge where it decreases down to -M.

$$\int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} g= \int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}}g + \int\limits_{t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}}^{t_i-\frac{\delta}{2}}g + \int\limits_{t_i-\frac{\delta}{2}}^{t_i}g$$

$$= \int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}}g + \left [ (t_i-\frac{\delta}{2})-(t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}) \right ]s_i + \int\limits_{t_i-\frac{\delta}{2}}^{t_i}g$$

$$= \int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}}g + \left [ t_i-t_{i-1}-\delta \right ]s_i + \int\limits_{t_i-\frac{\delta}{2}}^{t_i}g$$

However, it is also true that

$$\int\limits_{t_i-\frac{\delta}{2}}^{t_i}g \leq 2|s_i| \frac{\delta}{2}$$

and

$$\int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_{i-1}+\frac{\delta}{2}}g \leq 2|s_i| \frac{\delta}{2}$$

and

$$\left [ t_i-t_{i-1}-\delta \right ]s_i \leq \left [ t_i-t_{i-1}-\delta \right ] |s_i|$$

Therefore

$$\int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} g \leq |s_i| \Delta t_i - |s_i| \delta + 2|s_i| \frac{\delta}{2}+ 2|s_i| \frac{\delta}{2}$$

$$=|s_i| \Delta t_i+|s_i|\delta$$

Then we take the difference

$$\int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} s-\int\limits_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} g=|s_i| \delta \leq M \delta = M \frac{\epsilon}{4nM}=\frac{\epsilon}{4n}$$

Since we have n subintervals in the partition, we can assert that

$$\int\limits_a^b s-\int\limits_a^b g=  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |s_i| \delta \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\epsilon}{4n}= n\frac{\epsilon}{4n}=\frac{\epsilon}{4}$$